# call back function between two fragments?

Tags: android, interface, callback, fragment

i have first fragment and second fragment i want from the second fragment to make some thing in the frist fragent using callback with interface but i find this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
```

**interface:**

```
public interface MyProfileCallback

 {
    void callbackCall(Context con);

 }
```

**first fragment:**

```
  public class firstfragment extends Fragment implements MyProfileCallback
  {

public firstfragment()
{
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fisrt, container, false);

    /
  ...
    /       
    }
    @Override
   public void callbackCall(Context con)
   {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "calllllllllll baaaaaaaaaaaaack",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
 }
```

second fragment:

```
 public class secondfragment extends Fragment
 {

  MyProfileCallback mcallback;

  public secondfragment()
  {
    // Required empty public constructor
  }


    @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,     

Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second, container, false);


    mcallback.callbackCall(getContext());


    return rootview;
}
```

Comment: Where are you initializing mcallback?

Comment: you need to initialize  mcallback in your 2nd fragment

Comment: how to initialize it ? @Ram

Comment: MyProfileCallback mcallback = (MyProfileCallback) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentName);

Comment: Direct communication between fragments should be avoided. Is better to let the Activity to mediate. More about this in the developers [site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: Yes Gonji, i agree....

Comment: @RamPrakash What should I put inside this .findFragmentByTag(fragmentName), any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your second Fragment,

```
mcallback=refernce of your First Frgament;
```

And Call this method:

```
 mcallback.callbackCall(getContext());
```

Comment: Do you mind to let me know how you reference to the first fragment?